# How to include success tests as part of junit report from soapui-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit, automation, soapui

I have created a Test Suite from Soap UI with 10 test cases. I'm trying to run the tests via Maven using `soapui-maven-plugin`. Below is my configuration.

```
<pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
          <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>5.5.0</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
              <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.7</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <projectFile>src/main/resources/my-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
            <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/soap-reports</outputFolder>
            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
            <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
            <printReport>true</printReport>
            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
            <projectProperties>
              <value>env=${env}</value>
            </projectProperties>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Under `target/soap-reports` folder, I'm able to see the test results when I run `mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:test`. But `TestSuite.xml` file only has the failed test cases data, It doesn't have any data about passed test cases.

What changes I need to make to see the passed tests also in the folder `target/soap-reports`

Comment: Don't about maven. In  general, failed test information is need to look for more details and could be a potential issue and one might need the details when test is failed even to track the issue thru defect management tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, My test cases stricture was like below.

```
Test Suite 1
---Test Case 1
------Test Step 1
------Test Step 2
------Test Step 3
------Test Step 4
------Test Step 5
.....................
```

Rather than having them as individual test cases, I have dumped everything into a single test case and that's the reason why it was always showing as 1 test case passed or 1 Test case failed. Now I have modified my Test Suite to below and I can see both passed & failed test cases now.

```
Test Suite 1
---Test Case 1
------Test Step 1
---Test Case 2
------Test Step 2
---Test Case 3
------Test Step 3
.........
```